# Using less as a conditional

Tags: sentence, conditionals

In the following sentence

This will prevent the user from submitting his verification **less** he has a username that complies to our requirement

Is this a correct usage of the word **less**. In searching for a definition, I found nothing that supports the above usage of the word less.

Is there a better word to use here?

Comment: It's a shortening of _unless_

Comment: A mistaken shortening. Probably confused with the correct but really old-fashioned *lest*, in which case, the subjunctive *... he have ...* should be used.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of comments have mentioned, this is probably a misspelling spelling of the word *lest* or a contraction (maybe unintentionally) of *unless.*

Grammatically, I don't see a way for the word to be used as a conjunction here in standard English.